# VBA Vlookup for 2 workbooks and copy filtered data to new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I need help with the VBA code below, I am trying to do vlookup, then filter data and copy filtered data then paste to new sheet in active workbook. See code below.

```
Sub NAAgingPaste()

    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2

    Dim colm_1 As String
    colm_1 = "T1"
    Range(colm_1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "vlookup"

    Dim colm_2 As String
    colm_2 = "T2"
    Range(colm_2).Select
    Columns("S:S").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4

    Range(colm_2).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-16], 20180418AgingInvoiceTest.csv!C1, 1, FALSE)"
    Range(colm_2).Select
    Selection.Copy


    Dim LR As Long
    LR = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Range("T2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("T2:T" & LR)

    Dim colm_3 As String
    colm_3 = ("Invoice Aging Upsert_04_17_2018-17_55_37_success.xlsx")
    myRange = "A1:T"


    Range(myRange).AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:="=#N/A" _
        , Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=#N/A"

    Dim colm_4 As Range
    colm_4 = "A1"

    Range(colm_4).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Range(colm_4).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ChDir "C:\Users\RRF - 113\Downloads"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\RRF - 113\Downloads\todelete2018#.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
        CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: And what is happening with the code above?

Comment: This  myRange = "A1:T" needs an end row, this  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "vlookup" looks odd, and [avoid select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) if possible and remove the .ScrollColumn instructions which aren't required and Dim colm_4 As String not Range

Comment: And Declare  myRange  and put Option Explicit at the top of your module. Perhaps it is  myRange = "A1:T" & LR  ? And explicitly reference the sheet you are working with. You are explicitly using the activesheet most of the time and this changes when you add a sheet e.g.   .Range(colm_4).Select 'you are now in a different sheet